# How does callback really work in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, callback

Below is my code which has two callbacks and one get route

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
     res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/login.html');
});
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      console.log("first callback 1");
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
      console.log("first callback 2");
});
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
   // set locals, only providing error in development
      console.log("second callback");
      res.locals.message = err.message;
      res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  // render the error page
     res.status(err.status || 500);
     res.render('error');
     console.log("error send");
});
```

Basically here the two callbacks are for error handling.If I run the app and go to `localhost:3000/home` ,since there is no route and because of the call backs Ill get the 404 errror.

But if I go to `localhost:3000/login` ,it is displaying my login.html page but no call backs are getting called.Even though there is no error I mean atleast it should print first console message in the callback.But why it is not calling the callback?

What I read about callbacks is that if you don't specify any path,it gets called for all the routes.But why not here?Can someone take time to read this and clear me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You might want to try to put your `app.get('/login'…)` to the bottom.

Comment: @AlexPánek got now.But what does it mean..That callback should get called for all the routes..But why it didnt get called when it is at bottom..Can you please help me in understanding this

Comment: I don't know the details exactly, but it seems that any route handler (`app.get`) added before adding middleware (`app.use`) does not know about the middleware.

Comment: @AlexPánek .ok..But if I have app.get('/login'..) at top and  in res.sendFile, I give a html file name which is not present,it is going to bottom callbacks and displaying the console logs..why so??From your words   " route handler added before adding middleware  does not know about the middleware"..What is the reason here?

Comment: I haven't looked at the code of the framework you are using, so I really cannot tell you what is happening under the hood. This is just my gut feeling. I also wrote a comment instead of an answer for that reason. :)

Comment: @AlexPánek There isnt any much code..Im using express framework and i used I used express generator to get default code which by default get the error handling code.To that I added just the above route handler.But what I understand from you is even though if we have route handler above the middleware and if we are not sending back any response,it will not go to the bottom middleware and it will go only if we use next()..Am i correct?

Answer (score 2):

This is not about callbacks. It is about how the middleware (plugin/module) architecture work in Express (and incidentally lots of other frameworks, but be warned: not all frameworks work like this).

The real code implemented by Express is modular and a bit more complicated but basically it works something like this:

```
var middlewares = [];

var app = {
    use: function (callback) {
        middlewares.push({path:"", callback: callback});
    },
    get: function (path, callback) {
        middlewares.push({path: path, callback: callback});
    }
}
```

So you see, the idea is simple. There really is nothing fancy. `.use()` is used to add code you want to execute with all paths and `.get()` is used to add code you want to execute if the path matches.

So we can now process each request to the server by looping through the array:

```
// WARNING: NOT REAL CODE, this is only meant as an illustration

function processRequest (req, res) {
    for (var i=0; i<middlewares.length; i++) {
        var whatToDo = middlewares[i];

        if (whatToDo.path == "") { // no need to check path
            whatToDo.callback(err, req, res, next);
        }
        else if (whatToDo.path == req.path) { // check if path match
            whatToDo.callback(req, res, next);
        }
    }
}
```

So that's how it works. Of course, the middlewares are asynchronous so in the real code we can't use the for loop. That's actually what the `next()` function is for - to loop through the middlewares like a linked list (only, its linked functions). If no `next()` is called the loop stops.

Comment: If you're really interested about how to loop an array asynchronously I can add it to the answer. For now I think the above fake code is good enough to give you a hint of what the framework is doing

Comment: that was nice explanation and I guess I understood..It would be more helpful if you share good example  of how to loop array asynchronously...